# How to record the output of DLS synthesizer (kAudioUnitSubType_DLSSynth)?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-audio

I am developing an OSX application where I playback sounds through the built-in DLS Synthesizer (kAudioUnitSubType_DLSSynth) using Core Audio. I would like to capture the synthesizer output and export it to a file (.aif, .mp3,.caf, etc.). This seems like a straight-forward thing to do but I can't find an example anywhere. Recording from the built-in microphone is easy. This is hard.

Can anyone point me to an example or give me some tips?

Comment: Can you please post some of your code to show how far has your individual research come? Your callback function in particular? This will also help others to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are setting up an *AUGraph* consisting of two components: an output audio unit taking place of the *output node*:

```
AudioComponentDescription outputdesc = {0};
outputdesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
outputdesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
outputdesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
AUNode outputNode;
AUGraphAddNode(player->graph, &outputcd, &outputNode);
```

and an audio unit of `.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DLSSynth` "upstream" of it, taking place of the *instrument node*.

You can write and register an input callback of the *output unit*, not *instrument unit*, allowing for capturing whatever coems from "upstream". This is the simplest answer. The "how-to" is rather decently covered in a number of textbooks and code examples, but also requires a bit of individual research. Dealing with recording formats and format conversions is already a separate question, IMO.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am doing. Do I use AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback to register the input callback?

Comment: Ok, this helped me get on track to do some more research (into rendering). Thanks for the point in the right direction. Much appreciated.